# No default context on LocalContext.current

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, wear-os, android-jetpack, glance

Using LocalContext.current results in app crash telling me:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No default context
        at androidx.glance.CompositionLocalsKt$LocalContext$1.invoke(CompositionLocals.kt:35)
        at androidx.glance.CompositionLocalsKt$LocalContext$1.invoke(CompositionLocals.kt:35)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.LazyValueHolder.getCurrent(ValueHolders.kt:29)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.LazyValueHolder.getValue(ValueHolders.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.resolveCompositionLocal(Composer.kt:1776)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.consume(Composer.kt:1746)
        at com.bqubique.quran_randomayah.view.VerseCardKt.ButtonTile(VerseCard.kt:282)
        at com.bqubique.quran_randomayah.view.ComposableSingletons$VerseCardKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(VerseCard.kt:79)
        at com.bqubique.quran_randomayah.view.ComposableSingletons$VerseCardKt$lambda-2$1.invoke(VerseCard.kt:79)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at
...
```

Versions used:

compose_version = '1.0.5'

wear_compose_version = '1.0.0-alpha15'

I have tried calling LocalContext.current in any kind of @Composable, even in MainActivity.kt inside setContent{...}

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess the imports failed me. I was importing:

```
import androidx.glance.LocalContext
```

Instead of :

```
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
```